# When it comes to Upgradeable contracts, does Openzeppelin Initializable and Hardhat upgrades do the same thing?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

Openzeppelin Initializable suggests using initialize (initializer) method. Hardhat upgrades suggest to use a initialize method (even the name can be anything) and do that invocation during deployment/upgrade time. Does it mean these two means the same thing and achieve the upgradeable contract pattern in two ways? Can we use both of these together?

Came across this doubt when I was referring both of the patterns when I wanted to implement Upgradeable in my project.